# lxml append array element python3.6

Tags: python, lxml

I am building the xml format.

I want to do something like this:

```
<ValidationRequest>
<Username>admin@xgateinternal.com</Username>
<Password>XBR!t6YMeJbmsjqV</Password>
<Email>12345@gmail.com</Email>
<Email>564685@yahoo.com.hk</Email>
<Email>54321@yahoo.com.hk</Email>
</ValidationRequest>
```

Now I can append all email into ValidationRequest. But I got the wrong format.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import lxml.etree
import lxml.builder    

email = ['12345@gmail.com','564685@yahoo.com.hk','54321@yahoo.com.hk']

E = lxml.builder.ElementMaker()
ValidationRequest = E.ValidationRequest
Username = E.Username
Password = E.Password
Email = E.Email

op = []
for a in email:
    GG = Email(a)
    op.append(lxml.etree.tostring(GG, pretty_print=True))
    print (lxml.etree.tostring(GG, pretty_print=True))
print(op)
ed = ''.join(map(str, op))
print(ed)
the_doc = ValidationRequest(
            Username('admin'),
            Password('XBR'),
            ed
        )   

print (lxml.etree.tostring(the_doc, pretty_print=True))
```

The response:

```
b'<Email>12345@gmail.com</Email>\n'
b'<Email>564685@yahoo.com.hk</Email>\n'
b'<Email>54321@yahoo.com.hk</Email>\n'
[b'<Email>12345@gmail.com</Email>\n', b'<Email>564685@yahoo.com.hk</Email>\n', b'<Email>54321@yahoo.com.hk</Email>\n']
b'<Email>12345@gmail.com</Email>\n'b'<Email>564685@yahoo.com.hk</Email>\n'b'<Email>54321@yahoo.com.hk</Email>\n'
b"<ValidationRequest><Username>admin</Username><Password>XBR</Password>b'&lt;Email&gt;12345@gmail.com&lt;/Email&gt;\\n'b'&lt;Email&gt;564685@yahoo.com.hk&lt;/Email&gt;\\n'b'&lt;Email&gt;54321@yahoo.com.hk&lt;/Email&gt;\\n'</ValidationRequest>\n"
```

How can I keep <Email></Email> and post to ValidationRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea, there's just a lot there that's just moving stuff around. You can bring it down to this:

```
import lxml.etree
import lxml.builder

email = ['12345@gmail.com','564685@yahoo.com.hk','54321@yahoo.com.hk']

em = lxml.builder.ElementMaker()

the_doc = em.ValidationRequest(
    em.Username('admin'),
    em.Password('XBR'),
    *(em.Email(address) for address in email)
)

print(lxml.etree.tostring(the_doc, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

The `.decode()` is only there for it to print nicely. If you need the `bytes`, you can just leave that off.

Note this line in particular:

```
    *(em.Email(address) for address in email)
```

This loops over `email`, generating an `Email` element for each address as it goes, and then unpacking the resulting tuple (which is the result of the parentheses surrounding the generator) in to the constructor for the `ValidationRequest` element.

Output:

```
<ValidationRequest>
  <Username>admin</Username>
  <Password>XBR</Password>
  <Email>12345@gmail.com</Email>
  <Email>564685@yahoo.com.hk</Email>
  <Email>54321@yahoo.com.hk</Email>
</ValidationRequest>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This help me a lot